# Random “No application encryption key has been specified”

Tags: php, laravel

I have a website built on laravel 6.

Every things work fine. But there is a strange issue:
When browsing the website, i **randomly** get the error: **No application encryption key has been specified**. The error goes a way when i refresh the browser.

Lets say of 15 to 20 request, 1 or 2 requests fails with that error.

I am using laravel 6 years ago. I am quite aware of generating keys and clear cache so the problem is not here. More over if the problem is with configuration, then the website well not work at all. But in my case it works and i get that error occasionally.

I am using laravel valet on mac (imac 2020) and wamp server on windows 10 (hp core i7 hq). With php 7.3 and xdebug extension activated. The same problem on both machines.

I dont think its related to machine performance because are good enough.

Any one facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is possibly a mix-up with the session and the app's encryption key most likely.

Try running `php artisan key:generate` to create a new app key.